# How to improve eldoc + lsp-mode output with C/C++ comments?

Tags: lsp-mode, eldoc

When using eldoc with lsp-mode, there are some irritations with the default output.

- Various characters are backslash escaped, so:

  `/* This: isn't so -> "good", you see. */`

  Displays as:

  `This\: isn\'t so -\> \"good\"\, you see.`
- Blank lines are included so:

```
/**
 * This is a comment.
 */
```

Displays as:

```
This is a comment.
```

Has a blank lines above and below it.

---

Is there a convenient way to show eldoc as plain-text with blank lines stripped from the start & end, or does this require writing my own `eldoc-message-function` ?

Note while formatting for doxygen would be nice too, plain un-escaped text is fine.

Comment: Try this in your lsp-mode configuration: ```(setq lsp-eldoc-hook nil)``` - I have it and I do not have your described behaviour.

Comment: All this does for me is make eldoc not work in C/C++ code, you must have some other hook activating it for you.

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with lsp-mode getting strings in some format which it isn't properly preparing for display.

Comment: Yes, I have eldoc mode enabled in cc-mode package configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`lsp-mode` uses `markdown-mode` for rendering documentation which has issues regarding: see also https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/409 . If you want to render it in a different way you may modify `lsp-language-id-configuration`.

Comment: Can you expand on this? this map just maps the mode to a string, eg: `(c-mode . "c") (c++-mode . "cpp") (objc-mode . "objective-c")`

Comment: You should change the "markdown" entry in that map. It handles the markdown rendering.

Comment: I've removed this entry but the documentation renders the same as before.

`(setq lsp-language-id-configuration (assq-delete-all 'lsp--render-markdown lsp-language-id-configuration)) (setq lsp-language-id-configuration (assq-delete-all 'markdown-mode lsp-language-id-configuration))`